# A trick for calculating $n^6$ that I don't understand

Tags: number-theory

I was doing a math exercise and it asked to find what are the possible units digits of $n^6$ knowing that $n\in\mathbb Z$. The solution said that because we are concerned only with finding what the units digits of $n^6$ could be, it is sufficient to take the sixth power of numbers $0,1,2,\dots,9$ and the results would be our answers (which are $0,1,4,5,6,9$). How come this is true? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

What is the units digit of $340274513\times 384759374\,{}$?
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
& & & & 3 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 7 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 3 \\
& & & \times & 3 & 8 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 9 & 3 & 7 & 4 \\
\hline
& & & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 2 \\
& & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
& \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
& & & \vdots \\
& & & \vdots \\
\hline
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 2   
\end{array}
$$
The method of multiplying that you learned as a child shows you that the units digit in the product is determined by the units digits, and not any of the other digits, in the numbers that you're multiplying.

Moreover you can write the number $340274513$ as $\Big(34027451\times10\Big)+3$ and $384759374$ as $\Big(38475937\times 10\Big)+4$, and then you have
\begin{align}
& 340274513\times384759374 \\[10pt]
= {} &  \Big(\big(34027451\times10\big)+3\Big)\times\Big(\big(384759374\times10\big)+4\Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Big(\underbrace{\text{something}\times 10}_{\begin{smallmatrix} \text{This contributes} \\  \text{nothing to the} \\  \text{units digit.} \end{smallmatrix}}\Big) + (3\times 4)
\end{align}

Comment: An example is a nice way of explaining it

Comment: This is a good way of visualizing Eric's answer for a particular case :)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. By the binomial theorem $$(10a+b)^k=10^ka^k+\binom{k}{1}10^{k-1}a^{k-1}b+\cdots+\binom{k}{1}10ab^{k-1}+b^k$$ $$=10c+b^k$$ for some $c\in \mathbb{Z}$, so the units digit of $(10a+b)^k$ and $b^k$ are the same.

More generally, this follows since multiplication modulo $10$ (or any modulus) is well defined.

Comment: Nice! I like this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(10a+b)(10c+d) = 10(10ac+ad+bc)+bd$

This is just an algebraic way of looking at the long multiplication shown by Michael Hardy. Whenever we multiply two positive integers, the units digit depends only on the units digits of the original numbers.

This then obviously applies to three or more factors, and applies whether factors are the same or different.

---

The same logic applies to remainders on dividing by some number other than $10$

Comment: Would you mind to expand a bit on your last comment about remainders?

Comment: @space_voyager For example, working modulo $7$ i.e. with remainders on division by $7$, you go with $(7a+b)(7c+d)=7(\dots )+bd$ so you only need to know the remainder. That is an essential foundation of modular arithmetic, which becomes very important - which is why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more advanced but more general: For all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
(a\cdot b)\bmod n=(a\bmod n)\cdot (b\bmod n)
$$

Now apply this inductively with $n=10$ and note that the last digit
of a number is its residue mod $n$

Comment: And if anyone knows how to fix this spacing of the \mod..

Comment: The reason for the spacing you wanted to fix is the notation dating back to the publication in the year 1801 of Carl Gauss' book _Disquisitiones Arithmeticae_: $\Big( p \equiv q \Big) \mod n$, except the parentheses are usually not there: I've added those to emphasize how the expression is parsed. It means $p$ and $q$ both leave the same remainder on division by $n$.  More recently (after 1950, I suspect?) a different notation was introduced, by which $p\bmod n$ actually denotes the remainder when $p$ is divided by $n$.  In _that_ expression, $\bmod$ is $\text{a }\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$ binary operation symbol, and spacing should be what is appropriate to binary operation symbols.  In LaTeX and MathJax, it is coded as \bmod, where "b" stands for "binary".  The older notation is still standard, but now the newer notation also is standard.  Notice the three parallel lines in "$\equiv$" above; one says "$p$ is congruent to $q$, modulo $n$." ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I'm inclined to think the spacing in $(p\equiv q)\mod n$ is appropriate only in a "displayed" setting when "mod" is the last thing on the line, and in an "inline" setting there shouldn't be so much space. But that's not how LaTeX and MathJax work. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

If you do the calculations using pencil and paper then the units digit of $n^6$ depends solely on the units digit of $n$, whatever $n\in{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: Thanks, but this just restates what I said in my question (and what is stated in the solution), but doesn't help elucidate the "why".